# MPLAB PIC18 legacy project link no chipname specified

Tags: mplab

I'm trying to rebuild an old project using MPLAB IDE v7.60 with the XC8 compiler in C18 compatibility mode as documented in the [MPLAB C18 to XC8 C Compiler Migration Guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50002184A.pdf).

I've managed to get all of the source compiled but the linker step fails:

```
Executing: "C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc8\v1.32\bin\mplink.exe" ...
(902) no chip name specified; use "PICC18 --CHIPINFO" to see available chip names
(908) exit status = 1
Link step failed.
```

PICC18 --CHIPINFO returns the following for the 18F2580:

```
18F2580:8000:600
```

How do I provide this information to mplink?  I can't seem to find any documentation to describe how that is done.

Answer (score 0):

In MPLAB you can select the device for the current project from the menu Configure>Select Device... if you haven't done this already.
I would also suggest porting your projects to MPLABX, I have encountered less problems using it compared to the old MPLAB.